# Blazor server app in local IIS counter not working

Tags: iis, server, blazor

I follow the instruction to test in windows server 2016,
Install the IIS , with web socket feature enabled
install the net core hostbundle 3.1.9
create a sample blazor server app with Visual studio 2019.
it works well in VS 2019
then I publish it to local folder.
and in IIS ,
set the path to the folder
change the pool to "no managed"

then I browsesr the website, it works well , local all pages,
however when I switch to Counter page. and click the button, nothing happen.
it suppose to increase the count by 1 for each click.
what am I missed?
any help will be appricated.

Regards

Comment: Did you check the developer tools? Press F12 in Chrome and see what it says in Console

Comment: Thanks, you answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Sort out, the windows 2016 comes with IE 11, which is not support, installed a Chrome and all good.

Comment: Have your problem solved? If it has been solved, please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.